# jQuery UI - Unselect

Tags: jquery-ui

How could I remove the selection of a selected element (with http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/) with jQuery (UI)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a modification to Selectable that allows unselection: http://nicolas.rudas.info/jquery/selectables_sortables/